# Webkit img resize - ломаются пропорции

Tags: webkit, css

Есть картинка с `height:100%;`, лежащая в контейнере, который меняет высоту динамически.
При этом, высота img меняется, а ширина остаётся статичной и картинку плющит, это только в webkit-браузерах, blink не пробовал. Вопрос: как заставить img придерживаться собственных пропорций при изменении одного из размеров?

Answer (score 1):

У меня в вебкит такого [не происходит](http://jsbin.com/AViLIca/1/edit).
Попробуйте задать width: 100% или width: auto, может поможет.
Если нет, приведите пример, где это происходит. Не знаю, как иначе воспроизвести.

Comment: http://dreamstudio.su/pages/in_galery.html - если перейти на любую из страниц верхней линейки, которые используют другую высоту главного поля, то фотку плющит.